# Get value from an array and check for individual values

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements, get, distinct-values

I have 3 dropdowns `selects` (each drop-down has values from 0 to 25):

```
<select class="form-select" id="select1" name="select1">
<option selected value="0">label...</option>
<option value="5">label...</option>
<option value="10">label...</option>
<option value="15">label...</option>
<option value="20">label...</option>
<option value="25">label...</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select" id="select2" name="select2">
<option selected value="0">label...</option>
<option value="5">label...</option>
<option value="10">label...</option>
<option value="15">label...</option>
<option value="20">label...</option>
<option value="25">label...</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select" id="select3" name="select3">
<option selected value="0">label...</option>
<option value="5">label...</option>
<option value="10">label...</option>
<option value="15">label...</option>
<option value="20">label...</option>
<option value="25">label...</option>
</select>
```

I’m trying to calculate the **total score** for all 3 dropdowns using _GET:

```
//get select values
$select1= $_GET['select1'];
$select2= $_GET['select2'];
$select3= $_GET['select3'];

$totalValues = array($select1, $select2, $select2);
$totalScore = array_sum($totalValues);
```

But also use conditions as follows:

```
//if any values are between 5-9
if ($totalScore <= 15)
     { 
         //this is the condition I'm stuck on - checking for min/max values in the array
      if ($totalValues >= 5 && $totalValues <=9)
         {
         $rating = 5;
         }  
        
  }

//and the same logic below...
```

- if any values are between 10-14
- if any values are between 15-19
- if any values are between 20-25

What is the best approach to use?

I pased all 3 values into an array then am trying to use in_array() to check the above conditions.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please can you share the code you've tried, and the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @RobEyre added my code that I have so far. I've cleansed the `id`s and values for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your logic like below to support several cases:

- If any value is between 5-9
- if any values are between 10-14
- if any values are between 15-19
- if any values are between 20-25

  ```
  if ($totalScore < 15) {
   // If any value is between 5-9
  if ($totalValues >= 5 && $totalValues <=9) {
     $rating = 5;
   }  
  else if($totalValues >= 10 && $totalValues <=14) {
   // if any values are between 10-14
  }
  } elseif ($totalScore < 20) {
    // if any values are between 15-19
  } elseif ($totalScore <= 25) {
   // if any values are between 20-25
  }
  ```

Comment: That was along the lines of what I was thinking...
However, this doesn't work as it needs to check if ANY of the selects values are in the range NOT the total value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've solved it with this logic:

```
if ($totalScore <= 15)
{
    if ($select1 <= 5 && $select2 <= 5 && $select3 <= 5)
    {
        $rating = 5;
    }
    if ($select1 == 10 || $select2 == 10 || $select3 == 10)
    {
        $rating = 4;
    } 
}
```